# unable to capture command process id

Tags: linux, process

I am trying to capture the process id of the flume command with in a linux script.

the script is being executed in nohup mode : *nohup flume.sh &*

*flume.sh:*

```
flume-ng agent --conf . -Dflume.root.logger=info,console -Djavax.net.debug=info,console --conf-file FLUME_Surya.conf --name IBMMQ  --classpath $CLASSPATH -Dcom.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings=false
echo $! > /biph/edl/SG/jobs/Src-104000-IPS_SG/CUL_FLUME_PROCESS_ID.txt
```

after the script is execute the text file is still empty, please advice

Answer (score 2):

`$!` contains the process id of the most recent *background* job.  That is, job placed in the background by putting a `&` at the end of the line.  In your script nothing is put into the background, and thus `$!` is empty.  (The `echo` command line will open the file, creating it if it doesn't exist and truncate it if it does.  But it has nothing to write to it.)